# Multiple concurrent connections to Cassandra in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra

I'm developing a multi-threaded application in which each thread accesses Cassandra in Java.
Shall I create multiple clusters and close them after each access or multiple sessions?
Can I create the cluster or the session as static data members?

Here is the log I got when declaring both as static:

```
14:40:50.361 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
14:40:50.361 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692207/why-cant-we-share-cassandra-session-initialised-in-parent-process-to-child-proce/40692851#40692851

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing a multi-thread application I would create **Cluster and Session as static member**. Session maintain multiple threads per instance and is **thread-safe**. I would use one Session object **per keyspace**.

From cassandra-java-driver docs:

> Session instances are thread-safe and usually a single instance is
>   enough per application. As a given session can only be "logged" into
>   one keyspace at a time (where the "logged" keyspace is the one used by
>   query if the query doesn't explicitely use a fully qualified table
>   name), it can make sense to create one session per keyspace used. This
>   is however not necessary to query multiple keyspaces since it is
>   always possible to use a single session with fully qualified table
>   name in queries.

Comment: Thank you. I did that and it worked but after certain amount of time, the application keeps saying: "Was inactive for 30 seconds, send heartbeat ..." and stop processing.

Comment: Send hearbeat is normal, but heartbeat is not returned? Edit your question with the log you get

Comment: Your log is totally normal. It's a DEBUG trace and It's means that every 30 seconds there is a heartbeat to check connection is alive. As you can read  the heartbeat query was successful.

Comment: The driver maintains a separate connection to subscribe to events like topology changes (nodes added, removed or moved), status changes (node goes up or down), and schema changes (i.e. table added/changed).  My guess is if you are seeing a lot of heartbeat log messages it's for this connection since it is usually idle unless there are events such as those described.  In fact i'm guessing it is highly likely this is the case since the name of the connection is '127.0.0.1:9042-1' and the control connection is usually the first created.